# footnotesize in tables

Tags: tables

How to write footnote in tables please? I would like to give [1] in cell, which is link to text below the table. Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{title}
\footnotesize\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{[1]} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & R & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{P} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{~}& &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}\\
    \cline{1-3} \cline{7-9}
    & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7 & col8  &col9 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table}


\end{table}
 \multicolumn{9}{\footnotesize Čísla }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your question about footnote*size* or just about putting footnotes in a table?

Comment: I am sorry about putting footnotes in a table

Comment: try to use `threeparttabe`  or simple add manually `[1]` as superscript and add multi column cell in the last table row with text which you like to have as "footnote`. to have only a "footnotemark` in cell will confuzing readers ...

Comment: Thank you, but I have an error in code. What is wrong please?

Comment: Which error do you have? Please add the error message -- as usual here -- to your question ...

Comment: i test your mwe. it works fine. see my answer below and in+form me, if it gives you what you like to have.

Comment: @Elisabeth  - Should the `\footnotesize` directive apply to all material in the table, or just to the footnote(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- it is not very clear how you like to have your footnote
- with `\threepartttable` you can obtain the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{title}
\label{tab:mythreeparttable}
\footnotesize                       % used font size
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{| *{11}{c|} }
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{A\tnote{a}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & R & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{P} \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{~}& &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}\\
    \cline{1-3} \cline{7-9}
    & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7 & col8  &col9 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
   \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
    \item[a] text of the footnotes
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

if you like to have footnote marks in brackets, than add in preamble

```
\renewcommand\tnote[1]{\textsuperscript{[#1]}}
```

and you will obtain:

[image]

**edit:** in case that you like to have normal font size in table and only footnotes with `\footnotesize` fonts, than move command `\footnotesize` from the beginning of table to `table notes (see @Mico comment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\tnote[1]{\textsuperscript{[#1]}}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{title}
\label{tab:mythreeparttable}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{| *{11}{c|} }
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{A\tnote{a}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & R & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{P} \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{~}& &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}\\
    \cline{1-3} \cline{7-9}
    & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7 & col8  &col9 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
   \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]\footnotesize
    \item[a] text of the footnotes
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much and is it possible to do that with links?

Comment: `\tnote` hasn't hyperlinks.

Comment: @Elisabeth - Given that the footnote markers and associated footnote texts are not far apart, making them into hypertargets and hyperlinks would appear to be overkill. Are you maybe asking about how to color the footnoote markers?

Comment: @Zarko - I would move the `\footnotesize` directive from its current location to just before `\begin{tablenotes}`.

Comment: @Mico, i thinging about his, but from OP first mwe i guess that she like to have table in footnote size. i will add this asap.